# LabelEncoder vs. onehot encoding in random forest regressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, categorical-data

I am trying to use RandomForestRegressor using python. I know that for numerical columns there are no need to scale since only one column that lead to most information gain is used to split data. However it seems like we still need to convert categorical values to numbers so that our machine can understand.

I want to compare between labelEncoder and onehot encoding and want to understand reason why one would be preferred.

I am using dataset from [Beijing Multi-Site Air-Quality Data Data Set | Machine Learning Repository, Center for Machine Learning and IntelligentSystems](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Beijing+Multi-Site+Air-Quality+Data) and trying to predict PM2.5 value

my dataframe looks like this

```
        year  month day    hour   PM2.5    PM10  SO2 NO2      CO      O3    TEMP    PRES    DEWP    RAIN    wd  WSPM    station
0       2013    3   1         0     4.0     4.0 4.0  7.0    300.0   77.0    -0.7    1023.0  -18.8   0.0     NNW 4.4    Aotizhongxin
1       2013    3   1         1     8.0     8.0 4.0  7.0    300.0   77.0    -1.1    1023.2  -18.2   0.0     N   4.7    Aotizhongxin
2       2013    3   1         2     7.0     7.0 5.0  10.0   300.0   73.0    -1.1    1023.5  -18.2   0.0     NNW 5.6    Aotizhongxin
3       2013    3   1         3     6.0     6.0 11.0 11.0   300.0   72.0    -1.4    1024.5  -19.4   0.0     NW  3.1    Aotizhongxin
4       2013    3   1         4     3.0     3.0 12.0 12.0   300.0   72.0    -2.0    1025.2  -19.5   0.0     N   2.0     Aotizhongxin
```

First I use one-hot encoding

```
ohe_df = pd.get_dummies(data=df, columns=["wd", "station"])

y = ohe_df["PM2.5"].values
X = ohe_df.drop(columns=["PM2.5"]).values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

rf_reg = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,
                               criterion="mse",
                               n_jobs=-1,
                               random_state=42)

rf_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

train_pred_y = rf_reg.predict(X_train)
test_pred_y = rf_reg.predict(X_test)

print(f"train_MAE = {mean_absolute_error(y_train, train_pred_y)}")
print(f"test_MAE = {mean_absolute_error(y_test, test_pred_y)}")

>>>train_MAE = 3.7268903322031877
>>>test_MAE = 10.108332295400825
```

Then using same rf_reg I train and predict after using label encoder

```
le = LabelEncoder()

le_df = df.copy()
le_df["wd"] = le.fit_transform(df["wd"])
le_df["station"] = le.fit_transform(df["station"])

y = le_df["PM2.5"].values
X = le_df.drop(columns=["PM2.5"]).values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

rf_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
train_pred_y = rf_reg.predict(X_train)
test_pred_y = rf_reg.predict(X_test)
print(f"train_MAE = {mean_absolute_error(y_train, train_pred_y)}")
print(f"test_MAE = {mean_absolute_error(y_test, test_pred_y)}")

>>>train_MAE = 3.765413599883373
>>>test_MAE = 10.189870188659498
```

From this comparison one-hot encoding seems to perform better but my question is, is it right method to compare different encoding methods? And If yes, why does labelEncoding performing worse(even though by little bit) than one hot encoding?

Answer (score 4):

The two functions, `LabelEncoder` and `OneHotEncoder`, have different targets and they are not interchangeable.

From the `OneHotEncoder` [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) (emphasis mine):

> Encode categorical **features** as a one-hot numeric array.

From the `LabelEncoder` [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) (emphasis mine):

> Encode **target labels** with value between 0 and n_classes-1.
>
> This transformer should be used to encode **target values**, *i.e.* `y`, and
> **not** the input `X`.

So, the correct approach here for encoding the **features** is to use `OneHotEncoder`. Using `LabelEncoder` will additionally impose an *order* among the categorical features, as `0` is less than `1` etc, which is **not** correct for categorical features (this is not an issue for the *labels* in a classification problem, which `LabelEncoder` is all about).

In case your features are ordinal (does not seem to be the case here with `wd` and `station`), you should consider [`OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder) instead of one-hot

Comment: So for categorical values in X variables only method is OneHotEncoding?

Comment: @Ambleu no, there is the [`OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder), too, when appropriate. Check the documentation links provided (which in turn provide links to the appropriate sections of the User Guide), they are your best friend.

Comment: Thanks. So then say I used LabelEncoder with Ordinal Encoder, is my way of comparing two(Ordinal vs. one hot) acceptable practice?

Comment: @Ambleu not clear what you mean by "acceptable practice"; it all depends on the specific case data: as far as I can see, your `wd` and `station` features are not ordinal, so using `OrdinalEncoder` is not correct here (and renders any comparison actually invalid) and you should stick to OHE by default.

Comment: How come using LabelEncoder(did the job of Ordinal encoder) output similar performance?

Comment: @Ambleu answers to such seemingly innocent & straightforward questions are never themselves straightforward. There is actually not any underlying theory that says that it should or not, only best practices and common modelling sense.